# How do I duplicate an array with components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to duplicate an Array and I want to change the props inside the component in an array.
so this is my code:

```js
 const chartArray = [
    <Line
      key="o"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Bar
      key="p"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Pie
      key="q"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Radar
      key="r"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Doughnut
      key="s"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Scatter
      key="t"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <PolarArea
      key="u"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Bubble
      key="v"
      data={chartData[0]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
  ];
```

I want to make another same `const` with a different name and I want to change the `data` like this:

```js
const chartArray2 = [
    <Line
      key="o"
      data={chartData[1]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Bar
      key="p"
      data={chartData[1]}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
     ....
```

I could do this with copy and paste but the thing is there are a lot of things such as `<Bar> <Line>` or something like that so what I want to do is just reduce my code.

```js
const number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  const typeNum = number.map(num => type === num && chartArray[num]);
  const typeNum2 = number.map(num => type2 === num && chartArray2[num]);
  const typeNum3 = number.map(num => type3 === num && chartArray3[num]);
  const typeNum4 = number.map(num => type4 === num && chartArray4[num]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating constant? Cant you use a loop to handle this? Or you have some other requirement?

Comment: I need to pass to a component. and I need to use it separately

Comment: Can you update the question to include your another component where you will be using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a const with parameter as follows

```
 const chartArray = (chartData) => [
    <Line
      key="o"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
    <Bar
      key="p"
      data={chartData}
      options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
    />,
```

and in the other component use it like

```
const number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  const typeNum = number.map(num => type === num && chartArray(chartData[0])[num]);
  const typeNum2 = number.map(num => type2 === num && chartArray(chartData[1])[num]);
```

Comment: OH ! It is possible !! thanks so much !! i hope u have a great day !! i will try this right now !!

Comment: Glad i could help and please let me know if it solved your issue

Comment: Omg that's perfectly worked !! Thank u so much !!! I really hope your day goes well !!

Comment: God bless you !!

Comment: God bless you too!!